# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined using multer

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to upload an image using MERN and multer but I can't find the error in my code.

route.js:

[image: route.js]

model.js:

[image: model.js]

app.js:

[image: app.js]

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: Please add code as text rather than images of text!

Comment: Please add images using the image upload icon or press Ctrl+G to upload one. The images have not uploaded in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have forgot is: You need to send your post request as multiform. Set it in the header like this:

```
   axios.pos("url", { data } , {headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }});
```